# Как сделать выборку из BLOB колонки по условию?

Tags: html, sql, парсер, oracle, blob

В таблице есть BLOB колонка, и в ней в заархивированном виде хранится HTML файл.

Нужно сделать выборку из этой таблицы, и найти все записи, где внутри HTML файла есть определенный тег.

Кто с данной задачей сталкивался, как это можно реализовать в запросе? Или вообще, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: А в заархивированном виде, что это за вид?  Обычно нет смысла,  чтобы в запросе участвовала колонка с типом blob,  критерии выбора этой колонки, например, список ключевых слов или тегов,  хранятся в других колонках/таблицах.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример исходных данных (если файл, дайте ссылку на открытый файлообменник), и ожидаемый результат в текстовом виде.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Сделайте вот так:

```
create table tblob (name varchar2 (16), data blob)
/
declare 
    val raw (32767) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw (
    '<html><body><mytag>My tag</mytag></body></html>');
begin
    insert into tblob values ('mypage', utl_compress.lz_compress (val));
end;    
/    
select name, text, data from (
    select name, data,
        utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (
            dbms_lob.substr (utl_compress.lz_uncompress (data), 4000, 1)) text
    from tblob b)
where regexp_like (text, '<mytag>')    
/
```

Результат:

```
NAME     TEXT                             DATA            
-------- -------------------------------- ----------------
mypage   <html><body><mytag>My            1F8B080000000000
         tag</mytag></body></html>        0003B3C928C9CDB1
                                          B349CA4FA9B4B3C9
                                          AD2C494CB7F3AD54
                                          005236FA109E8D3E
```

---

PS Если решение не будет достатоно производительно, то возможно поможет индексация текстовой информации ещё до архивации, [как описано здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1181976/217579).

Comment: Пример хорошего ответа на плохой вопрос.